# Material UI Tabs indicator postion change while resizing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I used Material UI tabs on my page and have a sidebar on the right.
When I expand or collapse the sidebar, the active tab indicator position changes.
I have found [this related issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/9337) on GitHub. They have added an action prop to the Tabs component since to solve the problem.

I have tried to fix the problem with this solution. But it didn't work for me.
How can I fix this problem?

```
function MyTabs() {
  const tabsActions = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (tabsActions.current) {
      tabsActions.current.updateIndicator();
    }
  }, []);

  return <Tabs action={tabsActions}>{items}</Popover>;
}
```

This is my tabs component

```
export const BasicTab = (props: TabProps) => {
  const { data, disabled, type, actions } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const tabsActions = React.useRef<any>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (tabsActions.current) {
      tabsActions.current.updateIndicator();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <StyledTabs
        action={tabsActions}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="basic tabs example"
        className={type}
        variant="scrollable"
        scrollButtons={false}
      >
        {data?.map((item: TabItemType) => {
          return (
            <Tab
              key={item.id}
              label={item.name}
              disabled={item.disabled}
              disableRipple={item.disableTabRipple}
              {...props}
            />
          );
        })}
      </StyledTabs>

      {data?.map((item: TabPanelItemType) => {
        return (
          <TabPanel value={value} key={item.id} index={item.id}>
            {item.component}
          </TabPanel>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. You almost have it, 2 small things.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (tabsActions.current) {
      tabsActions.current.updateIndicator();
    }
  }, []);
```

The dependency array is empty. One option here would be to pass the state of your drawer/sidebar to this component and then use that in the dependency array for the useEffect. However, due to the asynchronous nature of React's rendering process, the indicator update might not reflect immediately. To take care of this you can make use of `setTimeOut()`. This will have a slight delay, and the indicator looks to bounce over but its the best I've been able to do.

This is how I made mine work:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (tabActions.current) {
        tabActions.current.updateIndicator();
      }
    }, 200);
  }, [isOpen]);
```

`isOpen` is being passed to my Tabs component by the parent, which again is the open/close state of the drawer/sidebar component.

You can use this [article](https://medium.com/@jugtuttle/material-ui-react-persistent-drawer-and-tabs-b9717bf8f5be) for reference as well.